# NTP crashes Raspberry Pi

Tags: sd-card, ntp, crash

I have a Raspberry Pi 3. I use it as a FTP-server provisionally.

Every 2/3 days it crashes because of a problem with the NTP. I have cut the power to reboot it.

I have the system logs which show the commands executed before the crash. But I am unable to understand where the problem is.

This is the first log (24 January):

```
Jan 24 19:17:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 24 19:17:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[657]: eth0: ADV fdc4:5833:f1d0::df2/128 from fe80::16cc:20ff:feb0:d748
Jan 24 19:17:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[657]: eth0: REPLY6 received from fe80::16cc:20ff:feb0:d748
Jan 24 19:17:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[657]: eth0: adding address fdc4:5833:f1d0::df2/128
Jan 24 19:17:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[657]: eth0: renew in 21600 seconds, rebind in 34560 seconds
Jan 24 19:17:08 raspberrypi systemd-hostnamed[702]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
Jan 24 19:17:08 raspberrypi dbus[404]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 24 19:17:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 24 19:17:09 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[394]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::745d:a1fd:6899:6691.
Jan 24 19:17:09 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[394]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fdc4:5833:f1d0:0:8be4:8659:f462:8495.
Jan 24 19:17:09 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[394]: Registering new address record for fdc4:5833:f1d0:0:8be4:8659:f462:8495 on eth0.*.
Jan 24 19:17:09 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[394]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::745d:a1fd:6899:6691 on eth0.
Jan 24 19:17:10 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[394]: Registering new address record for fdc4:5833:f1d0::df2 on eth0.*.
Jan 24 19:17:11 raspberrypi ntpd[682]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 fdc4:5833:f1d0::df2 UDP 123
Jan 24 19:17:11 raspberrypi ntpd[682]: Listen normally on 6 eth0 fdc4:5833:f1d0:0:8be4:8659:f462:8495 UDP 123
Jan 24 19:17:11 raspberrypi ntpd[682]: Listen normally on 7 eth0 fe80::745d:a1fd:6899:6691 UDP 123
Jan 24 19:17:11 raspberrypi ntpd[682]: peers refreshed
```

And this is the second log (27 January):

```
Jan 27 09:17:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 27 09:17:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[654]: eth0: DHCPv6 REPLY: Not On Link
Jan 27 09:17:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[654]: eth0: soliciting a DHCPv6 lease
Jan 27 09:17:09 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[391]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::745d:a1fd:6899:6691.
Jan 27 09:17:09 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[391]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fdc4:5833:f1d0:0:8be4:8659:f462:8495.
Jan 27 09:17:09 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[391]: Registering new address record for fdc4:5833:f1d0:0:8be4:8659:f462:8495 on eth0.*.
Jan 27 09:17:09 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[391]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::745d:a1fd:6899:6691 on eth0.
Jan 27 09:17:09 raspberrypi dhcpcd[654]: eth0: ADV fdc4:5833:f1d0::df2/128 from fe80::16cc:20ff:feb0:d748
Jan 27 09:17:09 raspberrypi dhcpcd[654]: eth0: REPLY6 received from fe80::16cc:20ff:feb0:d748
Jan 27 09:17:09 raspberrypi dhcpcd[654]: eth0: adding address fdc4:5833:f1d0::df2/128
Jan 27 09:17:09 raspberrypi dhcpcd[654]: eth0: renew in 21600 seconds, rebind in 34560 seconds
Jan 27 09:17:10 raspberrypi ntpd[679]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 fdc4:5833:f1d0:0:8be4:8659:f462:8495 UDP 123
Jan 27 09:17:10 raspberrypi ntpd[679]: Listen normally on 6 eth0 fe80::745d:a1fd:6899:6691 UDP 123
Jan 27 09:17:10 raspberrypi ntpd[679]: peers refreshed
Jan 27 09:17:10 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[391]: Registering new address record for fdc4:5833:f1d0::df2 on eth0.*.
Jan 27 09:17:12 raspberrypi ntpd[679]: Listen normally on 7 eth0 fdc4:5833:f1d0::df2 UDP 123
Jan 27 09:17:12 raspberrypi ntpd[679]: peers refreshed
```

I also have the whole log if somebody wants it.

Comment: I don't see any crashes here.

Comment: and certainly nothing to indicate ntp is the cultprit

Comment: yes, there aren't any errors or crashes....but whenever the raspberry crash, there are always the same commands before (the commands of the NTP).....i think it is the reason but i'm wrong maybe...

Comment: can i post other logs to help you?

Comment: have you configured ntpd differently from a stock distribution? Is your network reliable?

Comment: Hi, no i didn't change nothing at the ntpd. The network is good, i have never had problems with it

Comment: Note that ntpd appears to be reacting to something happening involving the network, so looking a little earlier in the logs may be informative.  I suspect ntpd is an innocent bystander, here.

Comment: Maybe....i see a lot of dhcpcd string before the crash but it's strange because i set my raspberry with a static ip...if you want i can post the log in this part

Comment: Please, **don't** change the title to "SOLVED". Accept your own answer to indicated that you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. After a lot of tests in the end I understood the problem. It is the SD card (Kingston 16GB UHS-1).

I replaced it with a better SanDisk Exteme Pro and the problem disappeared. Thanks a lot for the advice.

Comment: Given this solved your problem could you please mark the answer as correct. I've noticed you are using two different accounts here, it is possible upon request to have these accounts merged. Just having one account is going to keep things simpler.

Comment: Yes my dear friend....the problem was i forgot the password of my main account so i had to add a comment with my secondary account....fortunatly this morning i found my password so now i can write with this.....i changed the title (as you can see)....

Comment: Hi Christian, I'm a site moderator here. If you would like to merge your new and old accounts there's some advice on the procedure [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). If not [that's OK](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts), but please make sure you avoid cross-voting between the two.